# Copying text with Syntax Coloring from Notepad++ to HTML

Tags: html

I know about Plugins/NppExport section in Notepad++. It completely works for copying from NP++ to Word Documents and somewhere else like it.

But how about to a HTML page? I want to show some code examples on my page with syntax highlighting. If possible, directly from NP++ a way that codes can be copied.

edit: Thanks everybody, I have found it. If someone else needs: https://highlightjs.org/usage/

Comment: `<pre>` tag with custom css

Comment: Just use the export to HTML option - it's in the same menu. `Plugins->NppExport->Export to HTML` or `Plugins->NppExpor->Copy HTML to Clipboard`

Answer (score 0):

You can use highlight js which very easy and compatible with syntax highlighter for many languages.

[Download here](https://highlightjs.org)

You just have to use like

```
<pre><code class="html">your html content goes here</code></pre>`
```